# Load image as a File

Tags: java, android, image, file, bitmap

How can I load an image ".jpg for example" as a File ?

To be precise this file was saved using :

```
public static void saveFile(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String picName) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(picName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "io exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So I only have the name as reference

I tried that :

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Context context, String picName) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    try {
        fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(picName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
        fileInputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "io exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

It works but I need it to be a file

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to work with `File` objects, I recommend that you do so consistently. Use `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` as the base for building a `File` of where you want the file to go (e.g., `new File(getCacheDir(), picName)`). Then, use `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` for your I/O, replacing `openFileOutput()` and `openFileInput()`.

Comment: That file is a picture from camera intent. I need to display it in an ImageView / reduce it size. I only need it as a File to send it through POST request. Wouldn't it be more efficient to get the bitmap and convert it at that time ?

Comment: @An-droid: "Wouldn't it be more efficient to get the bitmap and convert it at that time ?" -- sorry but I do not understand what you mean by this.

Comment: I mean, wouldn't it be more efficient to work with bitmap for display purpose and convert it to File when i need to send it in post request ?

Comment: @An-droid: If you used `EXTRA_OUTPUT` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, then you already have a file, wherever `EXTRA_OUTPUT` said to put it. Creating a *second* file would be less efficient than not creating a second file. If you did not use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and you are working with the thumbnail `Bitmap` from `getParcelableExtra("data")`, you might delay creating the `File` until it is needed, particularly if the user might not elect to upload the file (e.g., presses BACK rather than clicks the upload-photo action bar item).